# How to recursively print text with a title using the find command

Tags: bash

I used a find command that spits out a list of files that includes a given string by doing

```
find /dir -name cat
```

and I am able to print the contents by adding -exec cat {} to the end

However, I wanted to be able to add a title before each file to separate them i.e.

***** path/file *****
so it would print out

```
*****dir/cat.txt*****
some text
*****dir/cat2.txt*****
some text
```

Is there a way to do this?
Also if I wanted to only display the contents of a single file, which is gotten by the find command, i.e.

```
find [path] -name [string] | head -1
```

and adding -exec cat is not possible.
how would I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find` command can take multiple `-exec` parameters, and will run each one for each file.

So you can use:

`find . -name \*.txt -exec echo "***** {} *****" \; -exec cat {} \;`

And for the new second part of your question:

`find . -name \*.txt -exec echo "***** {} *****" \; -exec cat {} \; -quit`